# How to dismiss Android context menu in Espresso test

Tags: android, android-espresso

My test long presses list item, opens context menu, but then how does one dismiss the context menu via `Espresso`?

Do I need to tap the screen outside the bound of the context menu? I've tried this, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Try UI Automator:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0'
```

To dismiss the menu:

```
UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation()).pressBack()
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately dismissing popup actions do not come out-of-box in Espresso. Tapping outside the bound of context menu should do the trick. Otherwise the easiest way is you can use [ViewActions.pressBack](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/action/ViewActions#pressBack()) action:

```
onView(isRoot()).perform(pressBack())
```

Or simply use one of Espresso convenient methods [Espresso.pressBack()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/Espresso#pressBack()):

```
Espresso.pressBack()
```